# Issue redirecting http to https

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect, ssl, https

I have to set the whole website using https. I've already set on `use in frontend area` option and forced the unsecure base url to use https.

Then, in order to permanent redirect old url to https, I've set the code below in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Unfortunately every http request is just redirected to the home page instead of the equivalent https page.

Any idea about solving this issue?
thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php` 

Modify method `protected function _checkBaseUrl($request)` from

```
protected function _checkBaseUrl($request)
    {
        if (!Mage::isInstalled() || $request->getPost() || strtolower($request->getMethod()) == 'post') {
            return;
        }

        $redirectCode = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('web/url/redirect_to_base');
        if (!$redirectCode) {
            return;
        } elseif ($redirectCode != 301) {
            $redirectCode = 302;
        }

        if ($this->_isAdminFrontNameMatched($request)) {
            return;
        }

        $baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(
            Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB,
            Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
        );
        if (!$baseUrl) {
            return;
        }

        $uri = @parse_url($baseUrl);
        $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri() ? $request->getRequestUri() : '/';
        if (isset($uri['scheme']) && $uri['scheme'] != $request->getScheme()
            || isset($uri['host']) && $uri['host'] != $request->getHttpHost()
            || isset($uri['path']) && strpos($requestUri, $uri['path']) === false
        ) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect($baseUrl, $redirectCode)
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }
```

to

```
protected function _checkBaseUrl($request)
    {
        if (!Mage::isInstalled() || $request->getPost() || strtolower($request->getMethod()) == 'post') {
            return;
        }

        $redirectCode = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('web/url/redirect_to_base');
        if (!$redirectCode) {
            return;
        } elseif ($redirectCode != 301) {
            $redirectCode = 302;
        }

        if ($this->_isAdminFrontNameMatched($request)) {
            return;
        }

        $baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(
            Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB,
            Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
        );
        if (!$baseUrl) {
            return;
        }

        $uri = @parse_url($baseUrl);
        $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri() ? $request->getRequestUri() : '/';
        $newUrl = rtrim($baseUrl, '/') . $requestUri; // PD-April-170
        if (isset($uri['scheme']) && $uri['scheme'] != $request->getScheme()
            || isset($uri['host']) && $uri['host'] != $request->getHttpHost()
            || isset($uri['path']) && strpos($requestUri, $uri['path']) === false
        ) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect($newUrl, $redirectCode)
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Under `system->configuration->web->Url Options` , set the flag `Auto-redirect to Base URL` to `Yes`.

Comment: No need for a core hack here. These kinds of things are a combination of base URL configuration, cached 301 heaters and not fully understanding what is going on. Use curl to test your redirects and use different redirect codes did Magento and apache to see which does what.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `system->configuration->web->Url Options` and set the flag `Auto-redirect to Base URL` to `No`.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. I tried to clean magento cache, varnish and memcache.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use this in your `.htaccess`

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```