# magento redirect http to https

Tags: magento-1.8, redirect, security, https

I want to redirect http requests to https on Magento CE 1.8. I followed the steps below, but none of the methods work:

```
system->web->secure->Use Secure URLs in Frontend "yes"
```

In my .htaccess file:

```
## workaround for HTTP authorization

## in CGI environment



    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]



############################################
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I also tried: [Issue redirecting http to https](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76994/issue-redirecting-http-to-https) and changed the file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php` but it still does not work.

Comment: Please go to admin side : system->configuration->web->Url Options and set the flag Auto-redirect to Base URL to No.

Comment: Did you change base secure url & unsecure url to https at  magento system ................Please check the setting

Comment: its not work.any suggestions to fix it

Comment: yes @ Amit Bera  that's the  the issue please post your comment as answer to accept

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do redirect http to HTTPS, based on my guess, which Magento version is you are using is not important.
just can follow these steps

1. your host/phpmyadmin
2. select your database
3. find `core_config_data` table in that
4. change the secure and unsecure urls here, which is https://www.domain.com/

Comment: After changed the secure and unsecure urls in core_config_data table, you need to reindex.

Comment: Did you changing  base secure url & unsecure url to https at magento system ...............in the setting it worked as @Amit Bera  i think your solution also valuable for that kind of situation i upvoted it